# Docker Compose Up is running while with the same image its not running the image?

Tags: django, docker

docker-compose up working fine. Screenshot attached.
Here is the docker-compose file

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9090
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    env_file:
      - .env
```

[image]

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /app


COPY . /app

COPY .env /app

WORKDIR /app/

RUN apk --update add python3-dev 

RUN apk add mariadb-dev mariadb-client

RUN apk --update add python3 py-pip openssl ca-certificates py-openssl wget

RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade --no-cache && \
    apk add --no-cache \
        gcc g++ make libc-dev linux-headers 

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install uwsgi
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --default-timeout=10000 --no-cache-dir


EXPOSE 9090
```

docker run testbackend_web:latest

Above Command not working with the build

Can someone help in the same?

Error in Container

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the Docker and Docker compose files?

Comment: ...as text, not as images, please.

Comment: @Stevy Done, I added both files. The objective is to user the .env file to set the project settings file.

Comment: @DavidMaze Hi, I added both files for the reference

Comment: What specifically doesn't work?  Just running `docker run` doesn't look at the `docker-compose.yml` at all; since you didn't provide a `CMD` in the Dockerfile it will in fact immediately exit, and it also won't publish ports without an explicit `docker run -p` option.  You probably want to use `docker-compose up` to run this.

Comment: @DavidMaze Basically I need to use the image build from ```docker-compose``` so that it can be used in ECS. But the image created from ```docker-compose --build``` is not working and getting exit without any error. With ```docker-compose up``` its working fine